# How to update User Defined Variable in JMeter in JSR223 Sampler?

Tags: java, jmeter

I'm new to JMeter & Java and now writing Authorization script for testing API.
I had some troubles with updating variable with `vars.put(key,value)`

Here is my code example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Base64;

public class StringToByte {
    public void main(String[] args) {
        String str_salt = "${salt}";
        byte[] b_salt = str_salt.getBytes();
        
        String str_pass = "c3000Hub";
        byte[] b_pass = str_pass.getBytes();
        
        byte[] b_pass_hash = new byte[b_salt.length + b_pass.length];
        
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] hash = md.digest(b_pass_hash);
        
        String pass_hash = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hash);
        vars.put("passhash", pass_hash);
    }
}
```

Variable in User Defined Variables just not updating and I've got no idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to explicitly  **call** this [`main()` function](https://www.journaldev.com/12552/public-static-void-main-string-args-java-main-method) in order to get it working, you declare it but I fail to see where it's being invoked
2. Change `String str_salt = "${salt}";` to `String str_salt = vars.get("salt");`, as per [JSR223 Sampler Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler):

> The JSR223 test elements have a feature (compilation) that can significantly increase performance. To benefit from this feature:
>
> - Use Script files instead of inlining them. This will make JMeter compile them if this feature is available on ScriptEngine and cache them.
> - Or Use Script Text and check Cache compiled script if available property.
>
>   ```
>   When using this feature, ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as caching would only cache first replacement. Instead use script parameters.
>   ```

Suggested code change (if you want to keep this class/method approach):

```
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables

import java.security.MessageDigest

public class StringToByte {
    public void main(JMeterVariables vars) {
        String str_salt = vars.get("salt");
        byte[] b_salt = str_salt.getBytes();


        String str_pass = "c3000Hub";
        byte[] b_pass = str_pass.getBytes();

        byte[] b_pass_hash = new byte[b_salt.length + b_pass.length];


        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] hash = md.digest(b_pass_hash);

        String pass_hash = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hash);
        vars.put("passhash", pass_hash);
    }
}

new StringToByte().main(vars)
```

or you can just do something like:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest

String str_salt = vars.get("salt");

byte[] b_salt = str_salt.getBytes();


String str_pass = "c3000Hub";
byte[] b_pass = str_pass.getBytes();

byte[] b_pass_hash = new byte[b_salt.length + b_pass.length];


MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
byte[] hash = md.digest(b_pass_hash);

String pass_hash = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hash);
vars.put("passhash", pass_hash);
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: This worked for me perfect! TY for your advise, i need to read groovy documentation better :D